# ms access forms how to create a simple query with filtering fields

Tags: ms-access

This is a simple scenario yet i am unable to find any relevant examples.

I have a sql query that produces two fields:

1 - the id of a vehicle and 
2 - the number of hours said vehicle has been used.

What i need to do is to generate a datagrid with the two columns that show the query results and a filtering textbox.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subform where the subform has your query bound to it and your main firm does not. Create a text field in your main form, then set that as the link between the subform and your main form. This will automatically filter your dataset each time the field is changed and then left so you might want to create a button just so people move out of your text box. Here is a link on subform in access...https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Create-a-form-that-contains-a-subform-a-one-to-many-form-ddf3822f-8aba-49cb-831a-1e74d6f5f06b?ui=en-US&rs=en-ZA&ad=ZA

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this would be a parameterized query. This would prompt a user for the 'filter' when the query is run.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-parameters-to-ask-for-input-when-running-a-query-c2806d3d-d500-45a8-8507-ec6af351b6ed

For the data grid view you would use a form.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-form-in-Access-5d550a3d-92e1-4f38-9772-7e7e21e80c6b

Comment: thanks for the idea. The parametrized query is close but not the thing i am looking for. I need the filter to be a permanent field on the form, not a dialog. Thanks again

Comment: You can do that with forms, check the second link i posted. It requires some building but you can have a dropdown to filter or a textbox.